# Hosting the certificates from CSP in Windows Store to be visible for other applications

Tags: certificates, cryptography

I am developing a CSP that performs electronic signature in the cloud and I want to use it from applications like Adobe Reader and Microsoft Word.

For this, the certificates from CSP (from the cloud) must to be hosted also in Windows Store with a link to the CSP. I found something similar in [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149948/propagating-certificates-stored-in-a-cng-key-store-provider) but it is for a CNG Key Store Provider (KNG). I tried to do like there and certificates are visible from Adobe Reader but when I chose one of them for signing my CSP isn't called.

Is the certificate propagation for a CSP different from the case of a KSP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the CSP was called but the problem was that adobe reader couldn't resolve all dependencies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).